# PostgreSQL ambigous query while deleting and joining?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-delete

I have the following query

```
DELETE FROM bookings 
    where "bookings"."memberId" IN (
      select "memberId" from "bookings"
      join "memberRoles" on "memberRoles"."memberId" = "bookings"."memberId"
      where "bookings"."memberId" = 1234
      and "bookings"."state" = 'MATCHED'
      and "memberRoles"."roleId" in (354,326,184)
    );
```

my expected output would be to delete whatever i asked it to delete, however, it returns an error in my `SELECT` inside the `IN`, the error is
`ERROR:  column reference "memberId" is ambiguous`

I tried to do `select "bookings"."memberId"` but then it'll say

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "join"`

Any ideeas?

Answer (score 0):

Qualify all column names.  I would recommend table aliases:

```
DELETE FROM bookings b
    where b."memberId" IN (
      select b2."memberId"
      from "bookings" b2 join
           "memberRoles" mr
           on mr."memberId" = b2."memberId"
      where b2."memberId" = 1234 and
            b2."state" = 'MATCHED' and
            mr."roleId" in (354, 326, 184)
    );
```

I don't think you need `in` for this, though.  You might want to test this:

```
DELETE bookings b
    FROM "memberRoles" mr
    WHERE mr."memberId" = b."memberId" AND
          b."memberId" = 1234 AND
          b."state" = 'MATCHED' AND
          mr."roleId" in (354, 326, 184);
```